# Increment decimal place by 0.05 in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'll start off by saying i have jut started teaching myself VBA about a week ago, so I may not be asking the right question, but...

I am attempting to write a loop in Word VBA that will increment a number calculated partially from text retrieved from bookmarks. I want it to round up to the nearest .05, so .87 becomes .90 and .21 becomes .25.

The module that I have written follows:

```
A = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SRebateIncome").Range.Text
B = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RebateDefault").Range.Text
C = ((A - 6000) * 0.15)
D = B - C
E = B + D
F = (18200 + ((445 + E) / 0.19)) + 1
G = (0.19 * 18200) + 445 + E + (37000 * (0.015 + 0.325 - 0.19))
H = (G / (0.015 + 0.325)) + 1
I = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TRebateIncome").Range.Text

If F < 37000 = True Then
    J = (0.125 * (I - F))
Else
    J = (0.125 * (I - H))
End If

K = E - J
K = Format(Round(K, 2), "###,##0.00")
'round K up to the nearest .00 or .05
If K <> "###,###.#0" = False or K <> "###,###.#5") = False Then
    Do
        K = K + 0.01
    Loop Until K = "###,###.#0" = True or K <> "###,###.#5") = True
End If

Set RebateOutput = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RebateOutput").Range
RebateOutput.Text = K
```

Now assuming that the value input for bookmarks "SRebateIncome", "RebateDefault" and "TRebateIncome" are 10175, 1602 and 43046 respectively, I expected the output to be 1460.80, but instead "K" is returned as 1460.78.

At this stage I don't know anything about using Excel within word (except copy/paste a spreadsheet into a document and I don't want to do that with this).

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Multiply by 20, round to the nearest whole number, then divide by 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an excel object and the Ceiling function

```
Option Explicit

Sub RoundText()

    Dim dblSRebateIncome As Double
    Dim dblRebateDefault As Double
    Dim dblTRebateIncome As Double
    Dim dblFinal As Double
    Dim rngOutput As Range
    Dim oExcel As Object

    ' Load the variables
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set rngOutput = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RebateOutput").Range
    dblSRebateIncome = CDbl(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SRebateIncome").Range.Text)
    dblRebateDefault = CDbl(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("RebateDefault").Range.Text)
    dblSRebateIncome = CDbl(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TRebateIncome").Range.Text)

    dblFinal = GetCalculatedValue(dblSRebateIncome, dblRebateDefault, dblTRebateIncome)

    dblFinal = oExcel.worksheetfunction.Ceiling(dblFinal, 0.05)

    rngOutput.Text = Format$(dblFinal, "###,##0.00")

End Sub

Function GetCalculatedValue(ByVal dblSIncome As Double, _
                            ByVal dblDefault As Double, _
                            ByVal dblTIncome) As Double

    ' Declare all the intermediate variables.
    Dim c As Double, d As Double, e As Double
    Dim f As Double, g As Double, h As Double
    Dim j As Double, ret As Double

    ' Perform the complicated calculation
    c = ((dblSIncome - 6000) * 0.15)
    d = dblDefault - c
    e = dblDefault + d
    f = (18200 + ((445 + e) / 0.19)) + 1
    g = (0.19 * 18200) + 445 + e + (37000 * (0.015 + 0.325 - 0.19))
    h = (g / (0.015 + 0.325)) + 1

    If f < 37000 Then
        j = (0.125 * (dblTIncome - f))
    Else
        j = (0.125 * (dblTIncome - h))
    End If

    ret = e - j


    ' Return the value of the fucntion
    GetCalculatedValue = ret

End Function
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x As Double
x = 1.111 'E.g.
Debug.Print Round(x * 20, 0)/20 '>> 1.10
```